# Initializing C++ class member array of objects with parametrized constructor

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose we have a class A with a parametrized constructor and another class B which contains an array of A objects as member. How do we initialize the A objects in the array using their parametrized constructor?

Here's what I've tried:

```
class A {
  private:
   int val;
  public:
   A(int v):val(v){}
};

class B {
  private:
   A a[3];
  public:
   B():a{(1,2,3)}{}
};
```

but then I get a compiler error "could not convert 'brace-enclosed initializer list()' from 'brace-enclosed initializer list' to A"

Comment: you do it like you would any other array: `a{(1,2,3)}` -> `a{1,2,3}`

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks! that worked! I'm a hardware guy; I get stucked with elementary SW development sometimes....

Comment: Do note that if you had a constructor with multiple parameters the syntax becomes `a{{param1, param2}, {param1_2, param2_2}, {param1_3, param2_3}}`